# Flutter setState inside an inner Widget

Tags: dart, widget, flutter, stateful

Is it possible to use `setState` inside a statefulls inner widget (outside of the main context)?

What I am trying to achieve is have the `Button` change `color` when a user clicks on it. It's inside a `ListView.builder` because there are multiple buttons but I want it only to happen in `_buildAnsers` widget

```
Widget _buildAnswers(int questionIndex) {

    //I need this to be inside this widget
    Color _buttonColor = Colors.red;

    return new ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 10,
      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, answerIndex) {

        return Padding(
            child: new RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _buttonColor = Colors.green; //this doesn't work?
                });
              },

              color: _buttonColor,
              splashColor: Color(0xFFde1f28),
              disabledColor: Color(0xFFc54b51),

              child: new Text('Container ${answerIndex}'),
            )
        );

      },
    );

  }
```

Comment: Do you want to change the color of only one button ?

Comment: The multiple that come from the ListView.builder. I ended up just making a `List` outside and put all the properties in there and used the List to change the colour

Answer (score 2):

no, it will not work, better option will be to use [StreamController](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-async/StreamController-class.html) and broadcast/subscribe model.

Comment: How do I make that work with what I have now? I'm not too familiar with `StreamController`s